# Como resolvo essa questão no visualg?

Tags: portugol

1)Faça um algoritmo,utilizandovetor para armazenar nome, tempo de serviçoe salário de 5 funcionários. Apresentar ao final A soma do totaldos salários antes e depois do aumento. O  programa  deverá calcular  o  salário  de  acordo  com  tabela abaixo,  sendo  necessário cumprir os requisitos apresentados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa questão precisa ser revolvida no visualg pois é uma questão de trabalho escolar

Comment: Rafael, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, adicione um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a sua pergunta para que a comunidade possa te ajudar. Colocando apenas o enunciado, dá a impressão de que quer que façam o trabalho por você :).